# How to express "to draw or write messily" idiomatically?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request, idioms, idiom-request

My kid "**drew or wrote messily**" on the paper (look at the picture)

[image]

> all over the place (British English also all over the shop) (US
>   English also all over the lot) (informal)
>
> 1-​**everywhere**
>
> New restaurants are appearing all over the place.
>
> ​2-**not neat or tidy; not well organized**
>
> Your calculations are all over the place (= completely wrong).

---

I am thinking about "**to write or draw all over the place**", but not sure if it is idiomatic.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "scribble." Another possibility is "scrawl."

Comment: So, maybe scribble or scrawl all over the page.

Comment: FYI, "all over the lot" is not, in my experience as a native AmE speaker, a common expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scribble](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scribble) is the word you are looking for.

> scrib·​ble | \ ˈskri-bəl  \
>   1: to write or draw hastily or carelessly
>   a note scribbled on the back of an envelope Harriet scribbled in her
>   notebook as soon as she took her seat. — Louise Fitzhugh He took a
>   stump of lead pencil out of his pocket and scribbled a moustache on
>   the lion's upper lip and then a pair of spectacles on its eyes.
>   — C.S. Lewis
>   2: to fill or cover something with careless or worthless
>   writings or drawings

Answer (score 0):

The verb I'm gonna tell you is not an idiom but i just wanted to share that with you:
To scrawl: to write in a careless and untidy way, so that your words are not easy to read